# Dataset of unknown islands?

Tags: aster

Recently I've reviewed ASTER GDEM v2 dataset and found many tiny (at least > 1ha) islets that's missing in other dataset such as WVS. I've change the altitude to 10m and they're still there.

Anyone/Organization ever attempted to documented/confirmed those? Or those are just defects?
I can't see them from Google Maps as the area isn't part of interest (no data).

Note: 
- ASTER itself limit their scope (1 square degrees) to area with at least a significant island. So there are possibility of unknown islets everywhere else.
- The area that I reviewed is not area of polar ice extent.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what your question is. If there is a dataset of 'unknown' islands, then by definition they are known, so they can't be called unknown.

Comment: I confused too :(. Because some are fall to nation's EEZ boundary then I guess some cant be named unless by the nation themselves. So I think a kind of consolidated of confirmed data. Whether it's a real island, its size or type of island.

Answer (score 2):

There are number of ways to check if they real or not. 
Cross validating data from other data sources would be what I would do:

- Check Landsat's TIR Band for thermal emmisions for day and night.
- Check Landsta's PAN Band, it has a resolution of 15 meters/pixel. It should be visible if your area is less than 1 Ha.
- Check SST (Sea Surface Temperature), which is a MODIS product (MOD 28 at reverb)
- Check [NOAA's shoreline database](http://shoreline.noaa.gov/index.html) if there's a shore at the AOI.

Comment: MODIS SST has a maximum of 1 km resolution, so I'm not sure it would help in this case (OP asks for > 1 ha).